# Include jpos.xml

Tags: java, thermal-printer, epson, javapos

I'm making POS system and now I'm trying set up pos printer epson tm-t20. When I try open port, where is a printer, I get this error message:

```
jpos.JposException: Could not connect to service with logicalName = POSPrinter: Exception.message=Could not create service instance.
    at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(Unknown Source)
    at tisk.Step1Frame.processWindowEvent(Step1Frame.java:83)
    at java.awt.Window.processEvent(Window.java:2009)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

I have `jpos.xml` generated, but I have no idea where to put it into the project..

Comment: Make sure all the dll files are added too. I had the same issue and adding the some more dll files from java/jre/bin solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

the file can be place any where but the root is the best place to start.

```java
    /*
     If you want to place the jpos.xml file elsewhere on your local file system then uncomment the
     following line and specify the full path to jpos.xml.

     If you want to place the jpos.xml file on a webserver for access over the internet then uncomment
     the second System.setProperty line below and specify the full URL to jpos.xml.
     */

    System.setProperty( JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "jpos.xml");
    
    System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_URL_PROP_NAME, "http://some-where-remote.com/jpos.xml");

error try adding this

      System.setProperty("jpos.loader.serviceManagerClass", "jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager");
      System.setProperty("jpos.config.populatorFile", "jposxml.cfg");
      System.setProperty("jpos.util.tracing.TurnOnNamedTracers", "JposServiceLoader,SimpleEntryRegistry,SimpleRegPopulator,XercesRegPopulator");
      System.setProperty("jpos.util.tracing.TurnOnAllNamedTracers", "ON");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I finaly found, that excetion was due to incompatibility between java pos and jre7. When I changed it to 6, I was able to open that port.

Comment: Sound more like a ext jar is conflicting. this could happens when a mix of  devices in the environment.